# Android NoClassDefFound inside an Android Library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, noclassdeffounderror, android-multidex

I have an Android library which I am using in two different projects. In one of them, I can use the library correcly. However, in the second project, I face the NoClassDefFound exception.

08-31 07:

```
49:23.155 7073-7073/com.my.android.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.my.android.app, PID: 7073 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.my.android.library.MyClass
```

The not-found class is inside the APK. I can see it inside the classes.jar
When I am debbuging, I can go into the code of the class, but when executing it, it crashes.
Finally, I installed the brand new Android Studio 2.2 and I used the APK analyzer and I can see the not found class exactly where it is supposed to be, inside classes.dex .

Answer (score 0):

Your project and library dependencies may have reached the 64K method reference limitation which causes to multiple dex files to be created.
To make sure the multidex is the source of the problem, try :

1- Add the `multidex dependency` to your project's `build.gradle` :

```
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

2- Add the  `multiDexEnabled true` to your `build.gradle` file :

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your.package.name"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

3- Create an application class for your project which extends MultidexApplication :

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication
```

4- Change the `AndroidManifest.xml` to use the MyApplication class as the entry point of the application :

```
    <application
    android:name=".MyApplication"  //the classpath to MyApplication
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: If multidexing would be a problem he couldn't build an APK from it in the first place.

Comment: Not true. As the he says the APK file can be created successfully but if the invocation target resides in another dex file, while the application is not an instance of MultidexApplication, then the NoClassDefFound exception occurs.

Comment: This is not the case

Comment: Did you try the multidex solution and the problem still exists ?

Comment: Yes... that's I why say that it is not the case.

Comment: Then you should explain more about this library project you are using. The problem may be in how you are exporting this library, proguard-setting, and ... . Try to be more specific, so that we can help to fugure out what's the problem. Also try yo run on different android versions to see if the problem occurs on all them or not. I have had such issues with KitKat

Comment: APK should contain all the DEX files. So if the APK was created, it should contain ALL the DEX files (one or several). I dont see your point.